Massive data import from remote CSV file using COPY command within a Edge Function
Im trying to achieve a massive data insertion (about 50.000) from a CSV file uploaded into Supabase Storage from the frontend, and process data inside a Serveless Supabase Edge Function, trying to make the insertion using the COPY command into PostgreSQL (Supabase) directly from the CSV file.
The sequence I'm trying is:

User uploads a large CSV file to Supabase Storage (about 4MB, like 50.000 rows)

A "job" row is inserted in "jobs" table in database, with the csv file location in Storage

A Supabase Edge function is triggered when the job is inserted


This function gets the CSV file location and creates a SignedUrl for downloading the CSV.
I create a PostgreSQL client using the "postgres" library for Deno (import { Client } from "https://deno.land/x/postgres/mod.ts") and instantiate with the Admin authenticated user.
I use the COPY command with signedUrl to try to make the insertion:
COPY reports FROM '${signedUrl}' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true)

I then got the error:
must be superuser or have privileges of the pg_read_server_files role to COPY from a file

When I try to grant that privileges to my user in Supabase SQL Editor:
GRANT pg_read_server_files TO my_user

I got the error:
ERROR: 42501: "pg_read_server_files" role memberships are reserved, only superusers can grant them

So... Im supposed to be the superuser or what? I'm the supabase project creator, it's my own account.. so what does this all means ? And how can I achieve what I want, if there's some other way.. please help!!

Read this  Supabase roles. superuser?
